# Save user Input using LocalStoarge in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML table and with 6 input boxes that requires user to enter data and as the user clicks on the input box it show save so when the the user the user refresh/reloads or closes the web-page and opens the web-page back up the data must show on what he entered previously.

I tried the simple method using local storage to get data entered by user to save and display for the first input box ("FY") but doesn't work because it get into conflict when i try to get and save the data from same place. so just to see if it work made the line of code to show under the FY box if when the user enters any data it will save and show but not working. Any help will appreciated

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  //                   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11  12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33
  var suffixes = ['', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];

  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sunday";
  weekday[1] = "Monday";
  weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
  weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
  weekday[4] = "Thursday";
  weekday[5] = "Friday";
  weekday[6] = "Saturday";

  var month = new Array(12);
  month[0] = "January";
  month[1] = "February";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "August";
  month[8] = "September";
  month[9] = "October";
  month[10] = "November";
  month[11] = "December";

  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = (weekday[today.getDay()] + ',' + " " + today.getDate() + '<sup>' + suffixes[today.getDate()] + '</sup>' + " " + month[today.getMonth()] + " " + today.getFullYear() + " Time:   " + today.toLocaleTimeString());
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}

// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Store
  localStorage.setItem("FY", document.getElementById("FY"));
  // Retrieve
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("FY");
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
```

```css
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.aligned {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
}

.corner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: right;
}

span {
  padding: 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 320px;
  margin-right: 770px;
  margin-top: -748px;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5px
}

.html2canvas {
  width: 1700px !important;
  height: 1700px !important;
}

table tr {
  background: #ffdead;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: white;
}

text-align: center;
body {
  background-color: #66b032;
}

h1,
th,
td {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

sup {
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <form name="apSafety" id="" apSafety "" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateChecklistForm()">
    <div class="aligned">
      <span>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<img src="Wal.png" width="120" height="130" alt=""></span> &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
      <b><h1>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Woodland DC </h1></b><b><h1 style="font-size:70px;">&nbsp;Safety Stats</h1></b>
    </div>
    <table class="center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>April Daily<br>Stats<br>&emsp;<br></th>
          <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>FY Goal % &emsp;<br></th>
          <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>OIR &emsp;<br></th>
          <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>Recordable Incidents &emsp;<br></th>
          <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>PIT Incidents &emsp;<br></th>
          <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>Total Incidents &emsp;<br></th>
          <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;"><br>Days OIR Free &emsp;<br></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- Today's Date is : &nbsp;<label id="text"></label>-->
          <div id="txt" style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;font-size:27px;"></div>
          &emsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          &emsp;
          <label for="FY"></label><br><input style="background-color: #151313;text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="FY" name="FY" value=" "><br>
          <div id="result"></div>
          &emsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          &emsp;
          <label for="OIR"></label><br><input style="background-color: #339214;text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;color: ##151313;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="OIR" name="OIR" value=" "><br> &emsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          &emsp;
          <label for="RI"></label><br><input style="text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="RI" name="RI" value=" "><br> &emsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          &emsp;
          <label for="PIT"></label><br><input style="text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="PIT" name="PIT" value=" "><br> &emsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          &emsp;
          <label for="TI"></label><br><input style="text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="TI" name="TI" value=" "><br> &emsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          &emsp;
          <label for="daysFree"></label><br><input style="text-align:center;height:80px;width:250px;font-weight: bold;font-size:65px;" type="text" id="daysFree" name="daysFree" value=" "><br> &emsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <b><h1 style="font-size:50px;">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Push instead of Pull</h1></b>
    <div class="image">
      <span>
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<img src="Safety1.png" width="450" height="500" alt="">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<img src="Safety2.png" width="850" height="450" alt=""></span>
    </div>
    <div class="corner">
      <span>
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                        &emsp;<img src="Walls.png" width="255" height="75" alt=""></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You're attempting to store an element reference in localStorage, and localStorage only stores strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event listener to keep storing data to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Replace `SOME_ELEMENT` for whatever elements you want to use and `SOME_DATA_KEY` with your preferred localStorage key.

**Edit: Use the `input` eventlistener**

```js
// Note: store your input element in a variable and replace SOME_ELEMENT with the variable
SOME_ELEMENT.addEventListener('input', function() {
    localStorage.setItem(SOME_DATA_KEY, SOME_ELEMENT.value); // Use .value to get and set text of input but use .textContent to get and set text of other elements (textareas, divs, etc.)
})
// This should run on script load
SOME_ELEMENT.value = localStorage.getItem(SOME_DATA_KEY);
```

Example (using a variable with ID of FY):

```js
let FY = document.getElementById('FY');
FY.addEventListener('input', function() {
    localStorage.setItem('FY', FY.value);
})
FY.value = localStorage.getItem('FY');
```

**Edit: [Do not use beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes) as it is not reliably fired.**

<strike>You can also use a different event to write the element value to localStorage. For example, you could use [`beforeunload`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiexKXAusLwAhVNrZ4KHV6DAw8QFjAAegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FWindow%2Fbeforeunload_event&usg=AOvVaw17Kqk5OU-NOgdTDEK0XCO5).</strike>

Comment: Thank you i manged to fix per your guidance and reference